# "-ing" em português?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia, fonemas

O som **[ŋ]** é o mesmo som de "*-ng*" em inglês; ex.: *I am **doing** fine*.

Creio que a regra seja "**[ŋ]** se `<n>` ou `<m>` estiver atrás duma sílaba, ou se vogal nasal em final de frase (há em "ele p**õe**"; mas não há em "põe isso"). Mas acho que pode ajudar eu escrever transcrições fonéticas usando o AFI/IPA (Alfabeto Fonético Internacional). Para quem não sabe o AFI, adicionei o som **[ŋ]** dentro da palavra em cada uma delas, ao lado da própria transcrição. Transcrições:

**[sɪ̃ŋ.paˈt͡ʃi.a]** Siŋpatia;

**[ˈsɐ̃ŋ.tʊ]**  saŋto;

**[sɐ̃]** Sã (não tem);

**[ˈtõŋ]** Toŋ;

**[ˈpõj̃]** Põe (não tem);

**[ˈbẽŋ]** Beŋ;

**[ˈfa.lɐ̃w̃ŋ]** Falaŋ;

**[fa.la.ˈrɐ̃w̃]** Falarão (não tem);

**[mɪ]** Me (não tem);

**[mĩŋ]** Miŋ;

**[kõˈmũŋ]** Comuŋ;

**[kõˌmũŋˈmẽŋ.t͡ʃɪ]** Comuŋmeŋte.

Por isto, acho esquisito escrever “comumente”, já que, no meu dialeto, “comumente” se pronunciaria **[kõˌmũˈmẽŋ.t͡ʃɪ]** comumeŋte, o que é inatural e esquisito para a minha pessoa. Para mim, apenas “comummente” (**[kõˌmũŋˈmẽŋ.t͡ʃɪ]** Comuŋmeŋte) faz sentido, pois falo assim.

Então pergunto: falar esse som (**[ŋ]**) é algo extremamente regional? Se possível, as regras que falei estão corretas?

Comment: Quais regiões teria este som?

Comment: @sumitani, eu moro no Brasil, em SP, em São Bernardo do Campo.

Comment: O "arquifonema nasal" tem uma variedade de realizações, uma delas sendo [ŋ] no fim da palavra e antes de [k g]. (Penso que tenha se equivocado na transcrição de "simpatia", "santo", pois a consoante nasal é usualmente no mesmo ponto de articulação que a seguinte.) Há outra pronúncia possível, como uma semivogal nasal como [ɰ̃]. Não acho que seja uma pronúncia estritamente "regional", já que as pronúncias possíveis são muito similares e só diferem na quantidade de movimento da língua; imagino que vários falantes tipicamente usem os dois sons.